# Fragment not showing up in ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a Fragment that I would like to scroll through since it will have content. I figured the easiest way to do this would be to add it to a ScrollView. I also think this might be doable with OpenGL ES, but I figured I'd give this a shot first. It did not work.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/CL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/sample_text">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/openGLES"
            android:name="com.example.hellooboe.OpenGLESActivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sample_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The fragment show up when it is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/CL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <fragment
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/sample_text">
            android:id="@+id/openGLES"
            android:name="com.example.hellooboe.OpenGLESActivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sample_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/openGLES" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What can I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/transparent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/openGLES"
        android:name="com.example.hellooboe.OpenGLESActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sample_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2" />

   </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! This gets me closer. Why does the fragment have to be in a ConstraintLayout to get drawn?

Comment: Nested Scrollview takes only a single child (in this case constraint layout)....if you need to add more content above and below your fragment then wrapping the fragment with constraint layout is advised.